# C - Opening a file and reading char by char with passing the file pointer as argument

Tags: c, file, stream

I am having trouble with understanding when i should pass the pointer and when the thing it points at. in my code:

```
int checkFile(FILE fp)
{
int c;
while((c = fgetc(*fp)) != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
}
fclose(*fp);

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "r");
char fileName = argv[1];
if(argc > 2)
{
    printf("Please supply a file!\n");
    printf("usage: CheckParenthesis <file name>\n");
}
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! trying to open the file\n");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    checkFile(fp);
}
return 0;
}
```

I get major errors compiling this, the error is:

```
    C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c: In          function 'checkFile':
C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c:17:22: error:     invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'FILE')
 while((c = fgetc(*fp)) != EOF)
                  ^
C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c:21:12: error:     invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'FILE')
 fclose(*fp);
        ^
C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c:28:21: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
 char fileName = argv[1];
                 ^
C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c:41:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'checkFile'
     checkFile(fp);
     ^
C:\Users\Dell\ClionProjects\CheckParenthesis\CheckParenthesis.c:12:5: note:   expected 'FILE' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'
```

int checkFile(FILE fp)

I know there are several problematics here but i do not know what will be right:
1. Am i opening the right argument? both argv[0] and argv[1] seem to be the file path i specified.. Adding this as a print out i made for getting the argv information:
test:

```
    printf("There are %d args, %s, %s\n", argc,argv[0],argv[1]);
```

result:

```
    There are 2 args,                    C:\Users\Dell\.CLion2016.2\system\cmake\generated\CheckParenthesis-    5dc89373\5dc89373\Release\CheckPare
nthesis.exe, C:\testing\brackets.txt
```

2. am i doing correct pointer usage?

Comment: you don't need to dereference the file pointer when passing as an argument

Comment: And the argument should be passed as `FILE*`, not `FILE`. The invoke from `main` is propert, but the function decl is not. It should be `int checkFile(FILE *fp)`

Comment: and `char fileName = argv[1];` is wrong, it should be `char* fileName = argv[1];`

Comment: why do you want to open argv[0]? argv[0] is the executable . You might want to use argv[1]

Comment: Thanks all it works now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew! So `checkfile()` should take a file pointer not a file. Change `int checkFile(FILE fp)` to `int checkFile(FILE* fp)` and then later in your while look you should change any `*fp` to `fp`

Your code should look like this:

```
int checkFile(FILE* fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "r");
    char* fileName = argv[1]; // thanks to dvhh in the comments
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Please supply a file!\n");
        printf("usage: CheckParenthesis <file name>\n");
    }
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error! trying to open the file\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        checkFile(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That should help, also can I see how you're compiling?(assuming you're using gcc)

Comment: change `char fileName = argv[1];` to `char* fileName = argv[1];`

Comment: Thanks that compiled fine!!

Comment: I use Clion.. so i compile through there. The problem that is now is that it prints gibberish instead of the actual content of the file.

Comment: @Eyzuky What do you expect it to print?

Comment: I really recommend using gcc or Visual Studio. Plus I think clion is pay to use.

Comment: Karthick thanks i had to switch between argv[0] and argv[1], now it works perfectly

Comment: I would recommend that you maybe check the number of arguments to main *before* you attempt to use those argument, also `fopen(argv[0],...` opens the *executable* (i.e "CheckParenthesis.exe") not the argument `<filename>`